# Learning JS - why do my elements not have any styles

Tags: javascript, watch

I'm struggling with my web page

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function(){
  var g = document.getElementById("guitar");
  console.log("Styles:", g.style.left,g.style.top, g.style.width,g.style.height, g.style.background);
});
```

```html
  <html>
    <head>
      <style>
    
      .stage {
     position:relative; width:400px;height:300px;background:brown;
      }
    
      .guitar {
     position:absolute;     left:20px;     top:10px;     width:150px;     height:150px;     background:#f63f63;
      }
    
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
      <input type="button" id="btn" value="Do something" />
    
      <div class="stage" id="stage">
        <div class="guitar" id="guitar" />
      </div>
    <body>
  </html>
```

If you note the last line of code,  I'm referring to the `g` for the guitar (I know bad naming etc, I'm just messing about here).

The question I have is, when I put a watch on `g` and expand the properties and navigate to style, there are none (there are no values in the list of styles). Even the background shows an empty value, yet the HTML is rendering it correctly.

Why can't I see the values in the watch Window?

[image]

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions Then **don't include the fuction**. Take out **all** code that isn't relevant, don't just remove function bodies but leave their invocations. I fixed your question so that it includes a minimal **complete** example that actually runs, but in the state you posted it, your question should have been closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `g` element doesn't have any style **attributes**...

You can see all of the style definitions on the 'computed style', as they are regular css declarations, and NOT defined via attributes.

Comment: Oh man.. this is it. I've gotten confused with class and styles

Answer (score 1):

Try window.getComputedStyle(g,null).getPropertyValue("height");

This should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style:

> The `HTMLElement.style` property returns a `CSSStyleDeclaration` object that represents only the element's inline style attribute, ignoring any applied style rules.

This means that if you have an element `<div style="left: 10px;">`, then its style object will contain the `left` value, but not if you only have a CSS rule `div { left: 10px; }`.

As already stated you can use `getComputedStyle()` to get the actual style applied by CSS.